# get number of columns of a particular row in given excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want the number of columns of a particular row in excel. How is that possible? I used POI API

but I could get only columns count to 7 .

```
    try
            {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("0");


                int numberOfCells = 0;
                Iterator rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
                /**
                 * Escape the header row *
                 */
                if (rowIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Row headerRow = (Row) rowIterator.next();
                    //get the number of cells in the header row
                    numberOfCells = headerRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                }
                System.out.println("number of cells "+numberOfCells);

}
```

I want the number of columns at a particular row number say 10 .
The excel columns are not same

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There are two Things you can do

use

```
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
```

or

```
int noOfColumns = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
```

There is a fine difference between them

1. Option 1 gives the no of columns which are actually filled with contents(If the 2nd column of 10 columns is not filled you will get 9)
2. Option 2 just gives you the index of last column. Hence done 'getLastCellNum()'

Comment: According to [`getLastCellNum()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getLastCellNum()), one is already added, so you _shouldn't_ add one yourself.

Comment: I also like the latter due to the explanatory name.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Count max number of nonempty cells in sheet rows */
private int getColumnsCount(XSSFSheet xssfSheet) {
    int result = 0;
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = xssfSheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            cells.add(cellIterator.next());
        }
        for (int i = cells.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
            Cell cell = cells.get(i-1);
            if (cell.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                cells.remove(i-1);
            } else {
                result = cells.size() > result ? cells.size() : result;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using `row.getLastCellNum()` gives you a higher value than what is actually filled in the file.
I used the method below to get the last column index that contains an actual value.

```
private int getLastFilledCellPosition(Row row) {
        int columnIndex = -1;

        for (int i = row.getLastCellNum() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(i);

            if (cell == null || CellType.BLANK.equals(cell.getCellType()) || StringUtils.isBlank(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                continue;
            } else {
                columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
                break;
            }
        }

        return columnIndex;
    }
```